# How to add a policy for an extension on Chrome (MacOS)?

Tags: macos, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

When I navigate to chrome://policy/ I can see the extensions I have that do support policies being applied.

How can I add a policy (possibly through a .plist file) to one of my extensions?

I know I can add a policy for chrome specifically through

`defaults write com.google.Chrome policyName -type value`

But how about policies for extensions?

Comment: [The documentation](https://www.chromium.org/administrators/configuring-policy-for-extensions/) (which you've seen) says the extension must use managed storage i.e. [define a schema and so on](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/manifest/storage/).

Comment: In this case the extensions I’ve been trying to apply policies do have managed storage..